# Should we allow texts which are without actual source?

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations

There are many texts that I am researching on which are just going on in the name of scriptures, but really if we dig deep, we don't really find any information. And these scriptures make big claims.

For eg:Shiva Gita without any source, Ashtavakra Gita, this seems to be an independent text.., Brahma Samhita - atleast they acknowledge it is recently discovered..

Below are some things that others also quoted but not available now.

Madhva quoted from books that are not available now like Maha Samhita, Chatur veda sikha etc..

Shri Vaishnavas quoted books that are not extant today.. I will update this as I find out the names. Their conception of sayujya being highest liberation seems to be based on a verse seen [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6943/where-is-this-srimad-bhagavatam-verse-about-the-different-forms-of-moksha), though it is not present today and bhagavat seems to reject all types of liberation.

These are quoted in some of their commentaries. Should we allow that portions to be cited.

I am researching on all the gitas and will update the list when I find credible information.

Should we allow these texts to be called or cited as scripture?

Comment: Ummm... How do we even know what is being quoted? Practically speaking, missing texts usually are not a big part of sampradayic literature, relatively speaking. They do acknowledge that it is missing, and the quoted material is very minimal, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

We should allow all scriptures that are traditionally accepted.

We are not experts. We can't even decide (in most cases) whether a particular answer is correct or not. With that being the case how do you think we will be able to decide whether some scripture is authentic or not?

That is most certainly beyond our capabilities. So, we should not poke our noses into that.

Just ask questions humbly and answer them humbly to acquire more knowledge and let interested readers know more unknown stuffs about Hinduism. That is our goal.

Regarding few texts you have mentioned in your question, like Shiva Gita, Astavakra Gita, they are highly revered scriptures in my place (West Bengal) as well as in northern India (I do not know much about how is the case elsewhere).

Ramkrishna Mutts and various other reputed publishers have made available these as books and which are considered as very important texts for Advaita related literature.

So, we have to accept them as authentic and move on. Same will apply to other texts you might be having doubts upon.

Thing to  understand here is that to add or change a single verse in a text is one thing and to write a whole text yourself and try to pass it off as if Lord Shiva (say) is speaking it is virtually impossible an task. We human beings are not that powerful. And, those who might have acquired such super-human capabilities, by Sadhana, will not do such criminal like activities.

So, we have to accept all of them and move on unless it is a text like say Allopanishad.

Comment: Allopanishad is the word of Allah. How dare you denigrate it ?

Comment: Did u downvote for that reason? @ram

Comment: i guess you didn't get the joke

Comment: Okay .. :D @ram